# Access diagonals of a matrix in Julia

Tags: julia

Errorbounds in Julia when dealing with matrices.

To get started with Julia I tried to access diagonals of a matrix. I believe it should be very simple. Yes I do know about the LinearAlgebra library please don't tell me to use the Diagonal function from there.

Suppose we have a 4 by 4 matrix A.

Then I tried to access the diagonal entries of A with the following code

```
for i in eachindex(A)
  @show A[i,i]
end
```

However, this gives me a "BoundsError: attempt to access 4×4 Matrix{Int64} at index [5, 5]".
I understand why this issue shows up, because if I simply type @show i into the loop then i=5 gives me the last entry of the diagonal, but i=5 is a bounds error.
Could anyone tell me what is a good standard way to Access specific entries of a matrix in Julia? And in this case how do I specifically access the diagonals of any matrix in Julia?

Comment: Accessing the diagonals of _any_ matrix in Julia is tough to answer: there are many different kinds of matrices in Julia, and the language allows users to create their own with weird indexing that you probably never thought of! `diag` and `diagind` are quite robust functions that have optimized methods defined for all of the matrix types you might encounter in base Julia (with sensible fallbacks for `AbstractMatrix` types as well). Is there a reason you want to avoid the standard library for your implementation?

Comment: @PaSTE, thank you for your reply, I am new to Julia, but I saw that in the documentation they suggest you to loop through matrices. I have to implement an algorithm where it is required that I restrict the diagonal entries of the matrix. Because of what was mentioned in the documentation and the more flexibility it gives you when you just access each entry I decided to do it this way, but I am of course open to different types of strategies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Matrices support linear indexing.

Consider the following matrix:

```
julia> A=collect(reshape(11:19,3,3))
3×3 Matrix{Int64}:
 11  14  17
 12  15  18
 13  16  19
```

In that case you can do:

```
julia> A[6]
16
```

16 is the sixth element of the array in the RAM memory (Julia uses columnar layout for arrays)

Since this efficient indexing a one dimensional index is returned by `eachindex`:

```
julia> eachindex(A)
Base.OneTo(9)
```

If you want to have a two dimensional index you need to provide the `IndexStyle` argument such as:

```
julia> collect(eachindex(IndexCartesian(), A))
3×3 Matrix{CartesianIndex{2}}:
 CartesianIndex(1, 1)  CartesianIndex(1, 2)  CartesianIndex(1, 3)
 CartesianIndex(2, 1)  CartesianIndex(2, 2)  CartesianIndex(2, 3)
 CartesianIndex(3, 1)  CartesianIndex(3, 2)  CartesianIndex(3, 3)
```

This of course can be changed to vector by using `vec()`.

Regarding "good way to access elements without LinearAlgebra" for your just want to have a loop such as `for i in 1:size(A,1)`. In some scenarios you will use this loop with  `@inbounds @simd` macros for efficiency.

Answer (score 2):

The error you see in your code is because you're iterating over all the indices of the matrix, including the ones that are outside the diagonal; that's what `eachindex` does. Here is a possible fix:

```
n = minimum(size(A))
for i = 1:n
   @show A[i,i]
end
```

This is similar to

```
inds = diagind(A)
for i in inds
   @show A[i]
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
julia> using LinearAlgebra

julia> x = rand(4,4)
4×4 Matrix{Float64}:
 0.860671    0.835563   0.619639  0.341792
 0.857668    0.788686   0.712648  0.234987
 0.223127    0.437224   0.773865  0.985331
 0.00618503  0.0744051  0.987713  0.345082

julia> diag(x)
4-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.8606711112971037
 0.7886860259341856
 0.7738651852069234
 0.34508203441346286
```

or this?

```
julia> diagind(x)
1:5:16

julia> x[diagind(x)]
4-element Vector{Float64}:
 0.8606711112971037
 0.7886860259341856
 0.7738651852069234
 0.34508203441346286
```

Comment: Well, you gave me the solution which I explicitly said I already knew about and that I wasn't looking for.